# Graph Union in Networkx

Tags: python-3.x, union, networkx

I have two graphs:

```
G.nodes() = [0,3]
H.nodes() = [1,2,3,4]
```

I am trying to merge the graphs together while only relabeling the nodes of H and maintaining the same labels for G so the resulting graph would have the following nodes:

```
U.nodes() = [0,3,1,2,5,4]
```

Where the first two elements are from G and everything else is from H given that there is a conflict of names at node 3 it gets renamed to the next available integer.

disjoint_union from networkx doesn't work because G.nodes() get relabeled to [0,1].

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: take a look at `nx.union` with the `rename` optional argument and then `convert_node_labels_to_integers`.  (anyone interested - feel free to build on this to give a full answer)

Answer (score 1):

Like @Joel states:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

_,ax = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(10,8))
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([0,3])
nx.draw_networkx(G, ax=ax[0], title='G')

H = nx.Graph()
H.add_nodes_from([1,2,3,4])
nx.draw_networkx(H, ax=ax[1])

U = nx.union(G, H, rename=('G-','H-'))
nx.draw_networkx(U, ax=ax[2])
print(U.nodes())
```

Output:

```
NodeView(('G-0', 'G-3', 'H-1', 'H-2', 'H-3', 'H-4'))
```

[image]